# Open Search Server File Crawler exclusively locking files

Tags: java, search, search-engine, opensearch, open-search-server

We've got a system using an old version of OpenSearchServer v1.4 - stable - rev 2274 - build 240.

We're finding, especially when the server is running slow, that files being crawled are being exclusively locked by the java.exe process.  We've established this by using process explorer and searching for the file that is being locked.  I shouldn't think there's any justification for a file crawler to exclusively lock a file whilst indexing its contents.

This is causing issues with other applications attempting to perform operations on the file.

Is this a known issue with OpenSearchServer? And has it been fixed in subsequent releases?